# Can you disable or hide reports?

Tags: civireport

We have a ton of reports, we would like to keep them but disable or hide them like we do with groups. Is that a functionality that I am just not seeing? Can you nest reports?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disable all the reports that derive from a certain template, but that's not exactly what you want. But for the record go to Admin - system settings - option groups and then scroll down to report template and click on Edit Options.

The civicrm_report_instance table does have an is_active field but it doesn't seem to be used. It would probably be medium effort to write an extension to customize some of the screens to allow setting that in the UI and then using it on the listing page. I assume that's the page you're talking about (from the menu under Reports), not individual report instance menu entries which can be disabled under Admin - customize - navigation menu.

Comment: Thank you - yeah, we might want to dev an extension for it.

Comment: Just had another thought - ReportInstance isn't available in api4 yet, but core seems eager to add stuff to searchkit, so the listing screen could be redone as a searchkit if somebody were to sponsor them to add ReportInstance. The ability to disable would then be available on that screen too via either inline edit or the Actions dropdown. If you're interested in that route then you could ask in the search improvements channel at chat.civicrm.org